# Chart doesn't display long-running WCF service? Timeout issue?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013, iis-6, windows-server-2008

We have a WCF method that generates a `json` for an amcharts chart. The chart then displays the data.

If the call is made for a short period (ie. 12/1-12/5) then the json is produced quickly and the amcharts chart shows the data.

On the other hand, if the call is made for all year, then the results will take longer to generate. Calling the WCF directly will generate the json in about 6-8 seconds. If the chart calls it, it never loads.

I've already confirmed that the issue isn't the WCF method since a json is eventually returned. I understand that the SP can be optimized, but that's another issue.

We use `IIS 6` on `Windows Server 2008`. The application pool for this particular WCF is set at `.Net Framework 4.0` and `Integrated`.

In terms of the project, we use `VS2013` and `C#`.

What do you recommend?

I tried increasing the timeout setting in `web.config`, but it didn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to configure all the related properties.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myBindingConfig"  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" bypassProxyOnLocal="true"   openTimeout="00:10:00" 
         closeTimeout="00:10:00"  sendTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" >
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" 
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

And servicebehavior, enable service debug to see the error in client

```
      <serviceBehaviors>
     <behavior name="myServiceBehavior">
  <dataContractSerializer  maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

      </behavior>

   </serviceBehaviors>
```